# I plucked on of my birds feathers on accident! Should I do something?

Tags: birds

I was just popping some of my birds ready pin-feathers, as a normally do. And I grabbed one and he freaked out and he made me accidentally pull it. There is a red wound on his head but he seems to be acting normal. Should I do something?

Answer (score 2):

Will be fine, pulling out a blood feather is only painful momentarily.

Comment: Absolutely right--it is not a problem. It's a good excuse for extra cuddles, though.